# How to create a central configuration of REST endpoints

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using the javax.ws.rs package to create endpoints in my standalone application. Is there a way to keep track of all routes and the class/method is relates to? I am hoping to find something similar to Laravel's routes.php or Struts' XML config. I could probably write a parser to generate something for me, but I want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: For documentation purposes? Then you may wanna have a look at [Swagger](http://petstore.swagger.io).